# How many different values can you get when you insert parentheses into the expression $5-1-1-1-1-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> How many different values can you get when you insert parentheses into the following expression? $$5-1-1-1-1-1$$

Here are some ways you can insert parentheses: $$5-(1-1-1)-1-1$$$$5-1-(1-1-(1-1))$$ Implied multiplication is not allowed: $$(5-1)(-1-1-1-1)$$

> How can I find this out? Is there a counting technique for this?

Comment: Please show the **different values** as well as the parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

The smallest possible number is $0$, largest possible is $8$ and since there are $6$ odd numbers add or subtract each other only even result can be obtained.

Feasibility of each even number:

$5-1-1-1-1-1=0$

$5-1-1-1-(1-1)=2$

$5-1-(1-1)-(1-1)=4$

$5-1-(1-1-1-1)=6$

$5-(1-1-1-1-1)=8$

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** $5$

**Solution:**
Note that since we have one $5$ and five $1$'s, the value of the expression must be even regardless of the order in which we do the subtractions. Subtraction is equivalent to adding the negation, so when we distribute all the minus signs, the first minus sign will stay a minus sign, but the remaining four minus signs can each either change to a plus sign or stay a minus sign. This gives us $5-1\pm 1\pm 1\pm 1\pm 1 = 4 \pm 1\pm 1\pm 1\pm 1$. (Note: the sign $\pm$ just means "either plus or minus"). The numbers that this expression represents are $0$, $2$, $4$, $6$, and $8$, for a total of $\boxed{5}$ possible values.